# How to center fixed width table on page horizontally? jsPDF with autotable

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm using jsPDF with autotable, I'm trying to center the table with fixed-width on generated pdf page. I can't seem to find a solution for this, everywhere I look is just full width, I don't want my table to be full width. I tried with margins option but It's not very precise and I'm not entirely sure how to calculate margins from A4 to horizontally center my table.

Screenshot:
[image]

```
document.querySelector(".report-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const pdfDoc = new jsPDF();
  const list = createListforPdf(); // function to generate list

  pdfDoc.autoTable({
    theme: "grid",
    tableWidth: 100,
    styles: { halign: "center" },
    columnStyles: {
      0: { cellWidth: 85, halign: "left" },
      1: { cellWidth: 15 }
    },

    head: [["MRZ Check number", "is OK?"]],
    body: [[list[0], "YES"], [list[1], "NO"]]
  });

  pdfDoc.save();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the margins in the following way:

```
let doc = new jsPDF();

let wantedTableWidth = 100;
let pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
let margin = (pageWidth - wantedTableWidth) / 2;

doc.autoTable({
    head: [['Name', 'Country']],
    body: [
        ['Leon', 'Sweden'],
        ['Magnus', 'Norway'],
        ['Juan', 'Argentina'],
    ],
    margin: {left: margin, right: margin}
});

doc.save('table.pdf');
```

Comment: That was exactly the solution which I was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

```js
var pageWidth = receiptPDF.internal.pageSize.width || receiptPDF.internal.pageSize.getWidth(); var wantedTableWidth = 60;
var marginTable = (pageWidth - wantedTableWidth) / 2

receiptPDF.autoTable({
  margin: {top: 0, right: marginTable, left: marginTable, bottom: 0 },
  cellWidth: 'auto',
  minCellHeight: 2
}
```

Please note, that the cellWidth property has to be set to 'auto' in order to work.

Answer (score -3):

Wrap the table with a div element.

```
<div class="table-container">
    <table id="my-table"><!--...--></table>
</div>
```

In CSS, write the class to center the table within the container.

```
div.table-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I don't use <table> tag in my app, I want to generate this through JS from data I will pass.